# Caption won't stick to table - gets centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

I'm trying to create a table with a caption on top of it, with the caption centered to the table.

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{float}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{This is a caption}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & 1\\ \hline
b & 2\\ \hline
c & 3\\ \hline
d & 4\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

What this does is create a table to the left of the paper (where I want it), but the caption appears in the center of the page, far from the table. I can center the table, of course, all looks fine, but I do need the table on the left of the page.

I searched around for similar problems, but what mostly found were people wanting to center tables, and I want quite the opposite, to uncenter the caption. Anyway, I did not find a solution to this problem so, if you can help, I appreciate it.

*Also: I am working in writelatex.com, if this helps*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) provides the `singlelinecheck` key-value:

> The standard LaTeX document classes (article, report, and book) automatically center a
>   caption if it ﬁts in one single line ... The `caption` package adapts this behavior and therefore usually ignores the justiﬁcation
>   & indention you have set with `justification=` & `indention=` in such case. But
>   you can switch this special treatment of such short captions off with the option `singlelinecheck=<bool>`.
>
> Using `false`, `no`, `off` or `0` for `<bool>` switches the extra centering off ...
>   You switch the extra centering on again by using `true`, `yes`, `on` or `1` for `<bool>`. (The default is `on`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\captionof{table}{This is a caption}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  a & 1 \\ \hline
  b & 2 \\ \hline
  c & 3 \\ \hline
  d & 4 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I've dropped the use of [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) and opted to use `caption`'s `\captionof{table}{<caption>}` which is similar to using the `[H]` float specifier. Depending on the location, you may have to issue a `\nobreak` to avoid `\caption`/`tabular` separation across a page break.